# How to change DataTables PageLenght select to bootstrap dropdown?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

Is there any easy or hard but proper solution to change in DataTables:

```
<label>
    Show 
    <select class="form-control input-sm" aria-controls="instruments" name="instruments_length">
        <option value="10">10</option>
        option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
    </select>
    entries
</label>
```

to something more like this:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">25</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">50</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">100</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks for help! :)

Comment: You'll probably have to do it like this: https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/449. Not so easy.